# R gganimate - GIF Animation Speed Is Incorrect?

Tags: r, ggplot2, animation, plot, gganimate

I have the following gganimate function:

```
animar <- ggplot(specdf, aes(x, y, colour=t_abbr)) +
  #fill="#78b833"
          theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="#78b833"),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom",
              axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank()) +
          geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE, 
                    fill = colorDict[[tgames$homeTeamAbbr[[1]]]]) +
          geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = x3, xmax = x4, ymin = y1, ymax = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE,
                    fill = colorDict[[tgames$homeTeamAbbr[[1]]]]) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = vertical_lines, colour="#FFFFFF") +
          geom_text(data = bot_nums, aes(nums, bot, label=txt), inherit.aes = FALSE, color = '#FFFFFF') +
          geom_text(data = top_nums, aes(nums, top, label=txt), inherit.aes = FALSE, color = '#FFFFFF', angle=180) +
          geom_voronoi_tile(
            data = subset(specdf, team != 'football'),
            bound = c(0, 120, 0, 53.3),
            mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = t_abbr, group = -1L),
            inherit.aes = FALSE,
            colour = "white",
            size = 0.5,
            alpha = 0.65
          ) +
          # home team velocities
          # geom_segment(
            #p_data = specdf %>% filter(team == 'home'),
            #mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x*sin(o), yend = y*cos(o)),
            #colour = colorDict[[tgames$homeTeamAbbr[[1]]]], size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))
          #) + 
          geom_point(aes(), show.legend= FALSE, size = 6) +
          geom_point(shape=1, size = 6, colour='black') +
          geom_text(aes(x, y, label = jerseyNumber), color = '#FFFFFF', size=3) +
          #{if(aes(jerseyNumber) == 22)geom_line()} +
          geom_segment(
            mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x + 0.5*s*sin(o*pi/180), yend = y + 0.5*s*cos(o*pi/180)),
            show.legend= FALSE, 
            size = 1, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))
          ) + 
          scale_colour_manual(values=colorDict) +
          scale_fill_manual(values=colorDict) +
          scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,120), expand=c(0,0)) +
          scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,53.3), expand=c(0,0)) + 
          coord_fixed() +
          labs(title="", x="", y="") +
          transition_states(time, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1, wrap = FALSE)

animate(animar)
anim_save("C:\\Users\\jakes\\Downloads\\thing2.gif")
```

This code works perfectly in my version of R (4.0.2) but not the current version (which other members of my team use). The result is the attached GIF: [image].

The expected output is below.
[image]

The code is the same for both GIFs. Is there a way to fix this other than downgrading everyone else's version of R to mine? Because my code works fine, it is hard for me to figure out what exactly is wrong, as the input data file is exactly the same. It looks like the GIF frames are being smeared across multiple frames and not taken at the expected intervals.

I understand this is a specific example (non-MWE), but I really need help with this and am hoping there is something easy that I missed. I rarely use R.

Comment: What is the exact version of `gganimate` you are using on the two different machines?

Comment: and can you maybe try to boil this down to a reproducible example with some simple data (and reduced code/ plot)? If this is a bug, this would really help everyone.

Comment: tip for reducing the code - remove all unnecessary `geom`s (geom_rect / geom_vline, possibly geom_segment), remove all `theme` calls, remove all `scale` calls. The problem seems not to be related to `geom_voronoi`, maybe try removing this too, and reduce the data to plot just a few dots and labels (and then share the data)